# moderncv apply one style to one heading and another style to body

Tags: moderncv, cv

I'm using `moderncv` and I want a `classic` heading with a `banking` body. That is, I want the layout of my name / contact info to follow `classic`'s formatting but the remainder of the CV to follow the `banking` format. How might I be able to do this?

For example, consider the following ideal case where I have a `header style` and a `body style` section:

```
% ============================================
% document setup
% ============================================
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% --------------------------------------------
% header style
% --------------------------------------------
\moderncvstyle{classic}
% style options: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue}

% --------------------------------------------
% header details
% --------------------------------------------
\usepackage{import}
\name{John}{Smith}
\address{1234 Main Street}{Chicago, IL}{12345}
\phone[fixed]{+1 (123) 456-7899}
\homepage{https://github.com/john-smith}

% ============================================
% CV content
% ============================================

% --------------------------------------------
% body style
% --------------------------------------------
\moderncvstyle{banking}
% style options: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'

% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
% begin
% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

% --------------------------------------------
\section{Experience}
% --------------------------------------------
\begin{itemize}
\item[]{
\cventry{June 2017 -- September 2017} % date
{Employee} % role
{Company} % company
{City, State} % city
{important} % role title
{\begin{itemize}% main text
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\end{itemize}}}

\item[]{
\cventry{June 2017 -- September 2017} % date
{Employee} % role
{Company} % company
{City, State} % city
{important} % role title
{\begin{itemize}% main text
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\end{itemize}}}
\end{itemize}

% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
% end
% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me (since it only reads the last style (body).

Comment: Welcome! Please provide code for a complete, minimal example which we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the several files of class `moderncv` you can find that the header of style classic is build by command `\moderncvhead{1}`.  Adding this command to the preamble solves your problem.

Please see the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{banking} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\moderncvhead{1}  % <===================================================

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} 
%\settowidth{\hintscolumnwidth}{Jun-Sep, 2011} 
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % for the 'classic' style

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}
\quote{Some quote}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{\textbf{Language} 2}{\textbf{Skill} level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}


\clearpage
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}          % use an optional argument to use a string other than "Enclosure", or redefine \enclname
\makelettertitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper 
neque sit amet lectus facilisis sed luctus nisl iaculis. Vivamus at neque 
arcu, sed tempor quam. Curabitur pharetra tincidunt tincidunt. Morbi 
volutpat feugiat mauris, quis tempor neque vehicula volutpat. Duis 
tristique justo vel massa fermentum accumsan. Mauris ante elit, feugiat 
vestibulum tempor eget, eleifend ac ipsum. Donec scelerisque lobortis 
ipsum eu vestibulum. Pellentesque vel massa at felis accumsan rhoncus.

Suspendisse commodo, massa eu congue tincidunt, elit mauris pellentesque 
orci, cursus tempor odio nisl euismod augue. Aliquam adipiscing nibh ut 
odio sodales et pulvinar tortor laoreet. Mauris a accumsan ligula. 
Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per 
inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse vulputate sem vehicula ipsum varius nec 
tempus dui dapibus. Phasellus et est urna, ut auctor erat. Sed tincidunt 
odio id odio aliquam mattis. Donec sapien nulla, feugiat eget adipiscing 
sit amet, lacinia ut dolor. Phasellus tincidunt, leo a fringilla 
consectetur, felis diam aliquam urna, vitae aliquet lectus orci nec 
velit. Vivamus dapibus varius blandit.

Duis sit amet magna ante, at sodales diam. Aenean consectetur porta 
risus et sagittis. Ut interdum, enim varius pellentesque tincidunt, 
magna libero sodales tortor, ut fermentum nunc metus a ante. Vivamus 
odio leo, tincidunt eu luctus ut, sollicitudin sit amet metus. Nunc 
sed orci lectus. Ut sodales magna sed velit volutpat sit amet pulvinar 
diam venenatis.

Albert Einstein discovered that $e=mc^2$ in 1905.

\[ e=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \]

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

and the resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: as a quick follow-up, how can I bold / change the color of the name in `moderncvhead{1}`?

Comment: @rrrrr you can use for example `\name{\textcolor[rgb]{1,0,0}{John}}{\textbf{Doe}}`  ...